# OWASP-ZAP: How to Pause traditional spider using script

Tags: owasp, zap

I have an requirement where I need to pause spider on the following condition

1. when response code is 302
2. when response header has location with value set to login page eg: "login.jsp"

Following is what I am currently doing
Script: HTTP sender
Engine: Jython
Script:

```
import httplib
HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 2031
APIKEY="2031"

def sendingRequest(msg, initiator, helper):pass
    
def responseReceived(msg, initiator, helper):
    if initiator == 3:
        try:
            h=httplib.HTTPConnection("{0}:{1}".format(HOST,PORT))
            if h:
                if msg.getResponseHeader() and msg.getResponseHeader().getStatusCode()==302:
                    if msg.getResponseHeader().getHeader("Location") is not None:
                        if "Login.jsp" in msg.getResponseHeader().getHeader("Location"):
                            h.request("GET", "/JSON/spider/action/pauseAllScans/?apikey={0}".format(APIKEY))
                            
                            
        except: pass
```

I was wondering if their is any other or better way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You havnt sai *why* you want to pause the scans. My guess is that so you can re-authenticate. If so then I think the better option is to configure ZAP to handle authentication, then it will automatically re-authenticate if the user ever gets logged out. If you really want to do it your way then you dont have to make an API call - your script is already running in ZAP and so will be able to pause the spider via code.

Comment: you are rite, I am trying to do an custom authentication mechanism And can you share some information on how i can pause spider from the code? I tried searching but I was not able to find, perhaps I have missed it somehow. If you can point me to the direction where to look for or what library to use it would be really helpful.

Comment: "How to do custom authentication" - thats a BIG topic. Have a look at https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/authentication/ Re pausing the spider by code - I dont think I can answer that properly in the space available here. The ZAP Dev Groupd would be a better place to ask: https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-develop